# can not insertSubView below another subView, ios

Tags: objective-c, ios7, subview, addsubview

I am implementing my own sliding view controller and the structure looks like below

```
ContainerViewController
   |
   |______FrontViewController
   |
   |______UIRearNavigationController (whose root is rearViewController1)
   |
   |______RearViewController2
```

Following are the methods to addSubViews

```
-(void)setupFrontViewController{
    [self.view addSubview:self.frontController.view];
}

-(void)setupRearViewController1 {
    self.rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.mainMenuViewController];    
    [self.view insertSubview:self.rearNavigationController.view belowSubview:self.inboxCubeController.view];

    [self setupRearViewController2];
}
-(void)setupRearViewController2{
    [self.view insertSubview:self.rearViewController2.view belowSubview:self.rearNavigationController.view];
}
```

When sliding frontViewController, I am seeing rearViewController1 underneath.However, if I slide rearViewController1, I would like to see rearViewController2. However, rearViewController2 is not shown at all (instead of it, I am seeing a white blank view controller )

**Question** : what have I missed in the middle and can we insert a sub-view below another ? sub-view

Please advice me on this issue. All comments are welcomed.

Comment: NSLog `[ContainerViewController subViews]`, make sure every sliding subviews have changed.

Comment: sorry what do you mean about this ?

Comment: I have just figured it out why I see the blank view controller when sliding rearViewController2.